# Error al intentar clonar repositorio de gitlab y bitbucket con sourcetree

Tags: git, control-de-versiones, bitbucket, sourcetree

tengo un problema al intentar clonar un repositorio desde gitlab o bitbucket utilizando sourcetree. El tema es que he creado varias veces la clave ssh, la he creado desde consola cmd y tambien desde el puty pero sigo con el mismo problema.

Aqui la clave ssh

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al clonar da siempre el mismo error.

Error con gitlab

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error con bitbucket

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor si me pudieran ayudar ya que he revisado tambien la authenticacion y está bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas usando la llave privada en el cliente ssh cuando tratas de clonar? Si es en git por terminal, hay que agregarla con `ssh-add` antes de clonar.

Comment: si estoy usando la privada

Comment: pero si ya tengo agregada la ssh desde puty por que habría que agregarla desde la terminal?

Comment: he intentado de todo y no he logrado clonar el repositorio